# Running multiple nested regression models in tidyverse workflow

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr, broom

I often want to run the same regression on both different subgroups of my data, and with multiple models (e.g. a bivariate model and one with controls). It seems to me that the purrr/tidyr/broom workflow of nesting, mapping and tidying should work well for this. I understand how to create the subgroups in a nest workflow, but I don't understand how to run more than one model and output a list of tidied regression results from each.

For instance this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  nest(data=-c(vs)) %>%
  mutate(
    fit = map(data,~lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = .x)),
    fit1 = map(data,~lm(mpg ~ cyl + gear + wt, data = .x)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy),
    tidied1 = map(fit1, tidy),
  ) %>% 
  unnest(tidied) %>% 
  unnest(tidied1)
```

generates the result "Names must be unique", presumably because it thinks I want to column bind the results, but bind_rows(tidied,tidied1) returns "object 'tidied' not found".

does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: What does your desired output look like?  Do you truly want a list of tidy objects?

Comment: Does that answer help is that what you set out to do?

Comment: My desired output is a tidy list of regression results with two extra columns, one designating the subgroup (in this case "vs") and the other designating the model (in this case "bivariate" and "wcontrol"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

Here's an option using nested `map` calls and avoiding having to unnest the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

# named vector so we can distinguish list results
formulae <- c(bivariate = mpg ~ cyl, 
              wcontrol = mpg ~ cyl + gear + wt)

map(formulae, function (y) 
  mtcars %>%
  split(.$vs) %>%
  map(~ lm(y, data = .x)) %>%
  map(~ broom::tidy(.)))
```

Per your update this goes straight to platting the models

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dotwhisker)

map(formulae, function (y) 
  mtcars %>%
    split(.$am) %>%
    purrr::map(~ lm(y, data = .x)) %>%
    dwplot() %>%
    relabel_predictors(c(wt = "Weight", cyl = "Cylinders", gear = "Gears")) +
    theme_bw() + xlab("Coefficient") + ylab("") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "grey60", linetype = 2) +
    ggtitle(paste("The model is", deparse(y, width.cutoff = 100), collapse=""))  +
    scale_colour_grey(start = .4, end = .8,
                      name = "Transmission",
                      breaks = c("Model 0", "Model 1"),
                      labels = c("Automatic", "Manual"))
)
#> $bivariate
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> $wcontrol
```

[image]

Comment: wow that makes a lot of sense. is it possible to output a tibble rather than a list? my goal is to pipe this to ggplot or dotwhisker:dwplot

Comment: how would one split by more than one variable in this specification?

Comment: Feed `split` a list of variables to split on `split(list(.$vs, .$am))`

Comment: do you know how one would make the second command work with more than one variable?

Comment: and do you know how with more than one grouping variable to make the first command create a tidy dataframe with rows designating groups? the current version outputs new columns for each group

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion is to add a `gather()` operation between fitting with `lm()` and tidying with `broom::tidy()`. This effectively consolidates all models into a single column and makes it easy to tidy with a single operation:

```
mtcars %>%
    nest(data=-c(vs)) %>%
    mutate(
        fit = map(data,~lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = .x)),
        fit1 = map(data,~lm(mpg ~ cyl + gear + wt, data = .x))
    ) %>%
    gather(name, model, fit:fit1) %>%        # <--- consolidate before tidying
    mutate(tidied = map(model, tidy)) %>%
    unnest(tidied)
# # A tibble: 12 x 9
#        vs data        name  model  term    estimate std.error statistic   p.value
#     <dbl> <list>      <chr> <list> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#   1     0 <tibble [1… fit   <lm>   (Inter…   36.9       3.69     10.0     2.73e-8
#   2     0 <tibble [1… fit   <lm>   cyl       -2.73      0.490    -5.56    4.27e-5
#   3     1 <tibble [1… fit   <lm>   (Inter…   41.9       5.78      7.26    1.00e-5
#   4     1 <tibble [1… fit   <lm>   cyl       -3.80      1.24     -3.07    9.78e-3
#   5     0 <tibble [1… fit1  <lm>   (Inter…   41.9       5.71      7.33    3.76e-6
# ...
```