# How to pass more than one argument to laply?

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to run a series of regression models and put the output relating to a particular covariate into an array. I've been able to do this with `laply` from the `plyr` package, like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                 x2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                 y1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                 y2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                 t2 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 t1 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))

run_regressions <- function(model) {
  model <- glm(model, data = df)
  return(summary(model)$coefficients[2,])
}

models <- list("y1 ~ t1 + x1",
               "y2 ~ t2 + x1 + x2")

results <- laply(models, run_regressions)
results
```

I would now like to extend this so that I can pass the different elements of the regression models to the run_regressions function separately. The regression function would be defined like

```
run_regressions2 <- function(outcome, treatment, covariates) {
  model <- glm(paste(outcome, " ~ ", treatment, " + ", covariates), data = df)
  return(summary(model)$coefficients[2,])
}
```

with the specific models to run specified as something like

```
models <- list(c("y1", "t1", "x1"),
               c("y2", "t2", "x1 + x2"))
```

Is there some way to use `laply` or another function to achieve this?

I've tried searching the `plyr` documentation for similar examples and searching SO for similar questions, but have not come up with anything.

Comment: The plyr package has been retired, and you may want to consider switching to a more current solution like dplyr's nested data frame structure or purrr's equivalent of laply. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227131/running-multiple-nested-regression-models-in-tidyverse-workflow

Comment: Thanks very much @jdobres - I didn't know that plyr had been retired. I've been looking into using nested data frames, and I see it's quite straightforward to do what I want that way.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @jdobres , `plyr` has been long retired. There are lot of modern replacements for it like `dplyr` and `purrr` package.

One option would be to use `lapply` in base R. In such case, the first case would change to

```
models <- list("y1 ~ t1 + x1", "y2 ~ t2 + x1 + x2")
results <- lapply(models, run_regressions)
results

#[[1]]
#   Estimate  Std. Error     t value    Pr(>|t|) 
#-0.42628388  0.20517578 -2.07765211  0.04038316 

#[[2]]
#  Estimate Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|) 
#-0.2966993  0.1991987 -1.4894639  0.1396433
```

---

In the second, case you can continue using `lapply` -

```
models <- list(c("y1", "t1", "x1"),c("y2", "t2", "x1 + x2"))

lapply(seq_along(models), \(x) 
      run_regressions2(models[[x]][1], models[[x]][2], models[[x]][3]))
```

Or more generally using `do.call` for any number of arguments.

```
lapply(seq_along(models), \(x) do.call(run_regressions2, as.list(models[[x]])))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Ronak Shah's final solution without having to use `models` twice would be:

```r
lapply(lapply(models, as.list), do.call, what=run_regressions2)
```

The inner `lapply` changes `models` into a list of lists which are then used as arguments to `do.call`.